# can angular decide which module to bring for the frontend or always travel the complete application with all the modules?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components

Can  angular 2 decide which module to bring for the frontend or always travel the complete application with all the modules?

Comment: You can use lazy-loading with or without the router https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load

Comment: Example:  { path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' }, loadChildren travel to backend and bring the new module?

Comment: Exactly. When the module wasn't already loaded previously, this results in a call to the server to load the module.

Comment: thanks you I will test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use lazy loaded routes / modules.

The docs:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router

With lazy routes, the components in that route are only loaded when that route is loaded. If a component is used in multiple routes however then it should be loaded in a shared module which should be loaded up front.

With lazy loaded route modules, keep an eye on the NET tab in your browser. Components in a lazy loaded route module should only be loaded when you first visit a route and you will see requests for components being made dynamically in the NET tab.

Here is a lightweight GitHub project that focuses on demonstrating lazy loading.

https://github.com/danday74/angular2-router-modular

This project is based on the Angular2 quickstart project. The only files that have been changed are the files in the app folder.

In particular pay attention to

https://github.com/danday74/angular2-router-modular/blob/master/app/app-routing.module.ts

Feel free to `git clone` it, then `npm install` then `npm start` to see it in action and have a play.